# Continuous function in the complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis

There are two define regions:
$K_1: z \in C: 1<|z-4i|<3$ and $K_2: z \in C: 5<|z-4i|<7$

I've to determine whether exists continuous $f: K_{1}\rightarrow R$ that $f(2i)=\frac{9\pi}{2}$ and $ z= |z|e^{f(z)}$ for all $z\in K_1$. If it's exists I've to find the function.

Similiraly, I've to determine whether exists continuous $f: K_{2}\rightarrow R$ that $f(-2i)=-\frac{9\pi}{2}$ and $ z= |z|e^{f(z)}$ for all $z\in K_2$. If it's exists I've to find the function.

I'm kind of lost in this question. I tried to use branch point and branch cuts, but I did not succeed in solving it.
Any ideas on how to approach this problem will help a lot!

Comment: I think that there is a typo in your question. It should be $f(2i)=i\frac{9\pi}{2}$. Same thing for the second case.

Answer (score 1):

Denote $f(z) = u(z)+i v(z)$ where $u,v$ are real maps. The equality
$$ z= |z|e^{f(z)}$$ implies $e^{u(z)} = 1$ for all $z \neq 0$, and therefore $u \equiv 0$ as $u$ has to be continuous.

You then get the equation $$ z= |z|e^{i v(z)}$$ where $v$ is a real function. The question is then related to the [complex logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm).

As $K_1 \subseteq \mathbb C \setminus \mathbb R_{\le 0}$ and the equation $z = \vert z \vert e^{f(z)}$ holds if we assume $f(2i)=i\frac{9\pi}{2}$, we can find a continuous $f$ satisfying the requirements.

For $K_2$, it is not possible because you can find paths included in $K_2$ with non zero [winding number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winding_number) around zero.